# Computing the Laplace transform of $\tan(pt)$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I've been  thinking of using  complex number approach , what's your view guys ?.

Comment: The singularities will make this quite challenging. My guess is you'll have to appeal to the residue theorem.

Comment: Oh.OK...can you throw more light please , am not really familiar with the residue  Theorem , though av  heard of it  & seen video tutorials on it....ain't they other  approach ?.

Comment: The Laplace transform of $f(t) = \tan(pt)$ doesn't exist. That's one of the reasons equations like $y'' + y = \tan x$ are interesting and challenging.

Comment: ^ but  the solution to the   D.E you put up there could easily  be determined by variation of parameters , maybe because The use of Laplace ..to solve D.E,s works suitably for IVPs ,

Comment: I think you have to calculate the integral in the sense of principal value, to get a Laplace transform of  $\tan(p t)$, and even then, it won't be that easy. I would not be surprised if the result involves some special function.

Answer (score 1):

Since:
$$ \cos(x)=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}\right)\tag{1} $$
by considering the logarithmic derivative of both sides we have:
$$ \tan(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{8x}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2-4x^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{-1}{x-\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi}+\frac{-1}{x+\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi}\right)\tag{2}$$
so $\tan(x)$ does not have a Laplace transform, but, at least formally, has a nice *inverse* Laplace transform:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\tan(x))=-2\sum_{n\geq 0}\cosh\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi s\right).\tag{3} $$
For practical purposes, we may consider partial sums for the RHS of $(2)$ or the RHS of $(3)$.

Comment: But what does this even mean?  You have a clear divergent series that represents an input (causal) signal. A partial sum does not represent the LT or the ILT in this case.  Maybe you had something more specific in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Using CAS like Mathematica we have:

$$\mathcal{L}_t[\tan (p t)](s)=-\frac{i}{s}+\frac{\Phi \left(-1,1,1-\frac{i s}{2 p}\right)}{p}$$

where:
$\Phi \left(-1,1,1-\frac{i s}{2 p}\right)$ is **HurwitzLerchPhi** function

Using:

$$\tan (x)=-i+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } -2 i (-1)^k e^{-2 i k x}$$

we have:

$$\mathcal{L}_t[\tan (p t)](s)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \mathcal{L}_t\left[-i-2 i (-1)^k e^{-2 i k p t}\right](s)=-\frac{i}{s}-\sum
   _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{2 i (-1)^k}{2 i k p+s}=-\frac{i}{s}+\frac{\Phi \left(-1,1,1-\frac{i s}{2 p}\right)}{p}$$

Comment: Also another identity: $\mathcal{L}_t[\tan (p t)](s)=\Re\left(\frac{\psi \left(\frac{i s}{4 p}\right)}{2 p}-\frac{\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i s}{4
   p}\right)}{2 p}\right)=\Im\left(\frac{i \psi \left(\frac{i s}{4 p}\right)}{2 p}-\frac{i \psi \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i s}{4
   p}\right)}{2 p}\right)$ where: $\psi \left(\frac{i s}{4 p}\right)$ is PolyGamma function.